# Symfony : How to use multiple mailers?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I try to configure the use of two mailers for several days and despite the documentation I can not. I currently have this code:
In swiftmailer.yaml :

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: first_mailer
    mailers:
        first_mailer:
            url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
        second_mailer:
            url: '%env(SECOND_MAILER_URL)%'
```

And in .env :

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://user:mdp@localhost
SECOND_MAILER_URL=gmail://user:mdp@localhost
```

I can not use them in my controller. How should I do it ?
With this ? :

```
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer');
```

If so, how should I implement it? Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by "I can not use them in my controller."? What's stopping you?
In general, as a good practice,  you should use dependency injection to provide services like mailer to your controllers instead of using container inside them.

Comment: Ok and how am I doing it? I tried with the dependency but I probably took it wrong. Could you tell me what to do? (sorry, I'm starting) Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide any code neither told what is not working (any errors or unwanted behavior etc.) therefore it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced similar issues when trying to setup multiple mailer accounts in Symfony 4 using SwiftMailer. Strangely the issues disappeared when I switched to "prod" mode.

For getting it working in all envs, here's how I set it up

swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
default_mailer: mailer
mailers:
    mailer_alerts:
        url: '%env(MAILER_ALERTS_URL)%'
    mailer_reports:
        url: '%env(MAILER_ALERTS_URL)%'
```

services.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        bind:
            $AlertsMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.mailer_alerts'
            $ReportsMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.mailer_reports'
```

Setup your service class to inject dependencies like below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

class MessagingService{
    private $mailer_alerts;
    private $mailer_reports;

    public function __construct($AlertsMailer, $ReportsMailer){
        $this->mailer_alerts  = $AlertsMailer;
        $this->mailer_reports = $ReportsMailer;
    }

    public function sendAlertEmail(...){
        $message = (new \Swift_Message($emailSubject))
        ...

        $this->mailer_alerts  ->send($message);
    }

    public function sendReportEmail(...){
        $message = (new \Swift_Message($emailSubject))
        ...
        this->mailer_reports->send($message);
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public function compute(Request $request, MessagingService $msgServ){
    ...
    $mailResponse = $msgServ->sendAlertEmail(...);
    ...
    return new APIResponse($statusCode, $statusMsg, $mailResponse);
}
```

Hope this helps you. I am still uncertain why binding the mailer service with \Swift_Mailer doesn't work in dev environment. It seems to use the default localhost:25 no matter what.

```
 \Swift_Mailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Swiftmailer documentation:

[Using Multiple Mailers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers)

when using autowiring only the default mailer is injected when type-hinting some argument with the \Swift_Mailer class.

If you need to inject a different mailer in some service you should also use the bind feature:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            # this injects the second mailer when type-hinting constructor arguments with \Swift_Mailer
            \Swift_Mailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'
            # this injects the second mailer when a service constructor argument is called $specialMailer
            $specialMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'

    App\Some\Service:
        # this injects the second mailer only for this argument of this service
        $differentMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry, this is my code :

```
#config/service.yaml

services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    bind:
        # this injects the second mailer when type-hinting constructor arguments with \Swift_Mailer
        \Swift_Mailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'
        # this injects the second mailer when a service constructor argument is called $specialMailer
        $specialMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'

    App\Some\Service:
    # this injects the second mailer only for this argument of this service
    $differentMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer'
```

and

```
#.env

MAILER_URL=gmail://user:password@localhost
SECOND_MAILER_URL=gmail://user:password@localhost
```

and this is swiftmailer :

```
swiftmailer:
   default_mailer: first_mailer
   mailers:
       first_mailer:
           url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
       second_mailer:
           url: '%env(SECOND_MAILER_URL)%'
```

and `$mailer = $container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer');` in my controller.

Error : `Invalid service "App\Some\Service": class "App\Some\Service" does not exist.`

and

```
Connection could not be established with host localhost [Aucune connexion n�a pu �tre �tablie car l�ordinateur cible l�a express�ment refus�e. #10061]
```

The mails are well sent.